# How insert fixed footer outside scroll view in constrain layout inside scrollview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, scroll, footer

I want to insert fixed footer bottom of the screen and above should be content in scroll view  I used below code but it's throwing exception  **ScrollView can host only one direct child**

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="mainActivity"
            type="com.example.footer.MainActivity" />
    </data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try is, it might be what you're looking for

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--        ScrollView can only contain 1 view inside-->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<!--            Use LinearLayoutCompat or ConstraintLayout or layout any-->
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <!-- do some thing -->
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </ScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is working I tried it yesterday, but instead of LinerLayout I used ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the constraints are not set correctly and changes to ScrollView layout_height and id are needed.

`ScrollView` requires an id `android:id="@+id/scrollView"`
and bottom constraint to be top of `TextView`  `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"`

`TextView` needs a top constraint to be bottom of `ScrollView`  `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView"`

Another issue was the height of `ScrollView` needs to use ["match_constraint"](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#match_constraint-dimensions-added-in-1.1) which is set like this in the code view of the layout: `android:layout_height="0dp"`

> When a dimension is set to MATCH_CONSTRAINT, the default behavior is to have the resulting size take all the available space.

Here is the final layout updated with above suggestions:

```xml
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="mainActivity"
        type="com.example.footer.MainActivity" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/footer">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```